# (403) Forbidden Error on IIS but IIS Express working fine

Tags: asp.net, json, iis, iis-express

I have a very simple asp.net website and basically it is calling an external API and returns JSON results.

It is working fine on IIS Express.
But when I change to Local IIS in Visual Studio project settings/web/Servers, I'm getting 403 error from API.

There might be something wrong with Authentication but couldn't figure out.

I am authenticating with the API with headers by the way. So it is not a windows authentication.

One additional note is I tested the API with Postman, Fiddler and it is working fine so I'm able to access to the API. So maybe there is something I need to do in application.config or most likely on IIS.

Edit:
I created a windows application and literally copied and pasted the code from the web app. And it worked fine.

Comment: Are you calling any 3rd party API or is it your own API? Also, is there any I/O operation involved e.g. saving data to file etc?

Comment: I'm calling 3rd party api and there is no I/O operation, it is a very simple request. I believe I changed something on IIS before.

Comment: First, learn what sub status you get https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0. IIS and IIS Express have different default settings, so such 403 can be expected.

Comment: Thanks for this but I'm not getting any inner exception and don't see anything in the logs for sub status. Please note that this is working fine with Fiddler, Postman, IIS Express as well. So I guess must be a setting on IIS security. Because the message is saying forbidden. So somehow I just need to send to API server something else.